# How to display a hidden div , from an anchor tag inside the google's map script

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: " <strong>Name</strong>  <br/> Aba Hillel Silver St 71 <br/>AvgPrice : 320$ <div class='stars starrr' data-rating='0'></div> <div class=''><a class='more_map_but' href='#gympagesection'>More Details</a></div>"
});
```

Here, at my class of anchor "more_map_but" I want if user clicks on it, there is a display:none div in HTML Code to be displayed, but it is just not working with my jquery code inside map script, else outside i.e., in rest of the page its working fine.

Following is my jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".more_map_but").click(function() {
            $(".appearing-section").fadeIn('slow');
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `event` delegation technique of `jQuery` like follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", ".more_map_but", function() {
            $(".appearing-section").fadeIn('slow');
        })
    })
</script>
```

Here we are attaching the event first to `document` and then delegating it to required `element`. This technique can be used for existing `elements` as well as elements which will be there in DOM in future. I am sure it will work.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm new here .. do i have to do something more now with this post ?? i didn't see any accept option ?

Comment: are you able to see tick mark below answer's up vote/down vote count below vote arrow images?

Comment: Yes and when i clicked it shows a message "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score".. may be thats why its not taking my vote now/

Comment: yes..thats true. You can't upvote if your rep is below 15. But still you can accept the answer. See this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: got it , i clicked the check option .. Thanks Again :)

Comment: Thanks @Azhar...`:)`!

Comment: i have one more query , please have a look at it. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233819/whenever-i-click-on-any-of-the-next-prev-button-for-the-first-time-it-slide-th