# whenever i click on any of the next/prev button for the first time , it slide the screen a bit upwards ? why is that so ? Please suggest something

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

the HTML is here : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/6GzOP

so After adding following simple HTML and CSS , below is my jquery which i added but its sliding up the frame a little which overlaps with my navbar . please suggest what to do , in order to fix this.

Following is my jquery :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
    });

    $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());


   $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
        var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
        var id = parseInt(id);
        $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
    });



    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
             var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
            $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
    });
```

});

Comment: That link is working fine for me

Comment: suspect a css overflow issue. Check your CSS.

Comment: oh ! my bad :p the link is this : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-extended-320-compatible @Sumi

Comment: there is a small css ; .hide-bullets {
list-style:none;
margin-left: -40px;
margin-top:20px;
}

thats it